# API documentation for the yaml-cpp library

Tags: c++, api, parsing, documentation, yaml

I decided to use the yaml-cpp v0.3 library to parse a config file for a FOSS daemon I maintain. I've decided to move to the new 0.5 API but my biggest problem so far is that there does not seem to be any proper documentation other than this:

https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial

...and some third party tutorials which are nice as an intro but there do not seem to be any Doxygen comments in the yaml-cpp source code. Is there a Doxygen like API overview somewhere? I rather like this new API but the lack of documentation makes it unnecessarily tiresome to work with.

Answer (score 2):

There is a doxygen build available here:

https://codedocs.xyz/jbeder/yaml-cpp/index.html

This is official and linked to from the github main readme. The code seems to be intentionally comment-free, but it might still be easier to use than browsing the header files yourself.